# Why should I use wildcards in preference to type parameters?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm reading Effective Java 2nd Edition, and in [Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA139&ots=yZIjQiq0N_&dq=effective%20java%20use%20bounded%20wildcards&pg=PA139#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20use%20bounded%20wildcards&f=false) there is the following:

> ```
> // Two possible declarations for the swap method
>
> public static <E> void swap(List<E> list, int i, int j);
> public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j);
> ```
>
> Which of these two declarations is preferable, and why? In a public
>   API, the second is better because it’s simpler. You pass in a list—any
>   list—and the method swaps the indexed elements. There is no type
>   parameter to worry about. As a rule, if a type parameter appears only
>   once in a method declaration, replace it with a wildcard.

I test it using the unbounded type parameter and I don't see any disadvantage, I can pass any list and I had no problems with type parameter, actually the unbounded type parameter was better, because I don't needed a helper method as explains on the sequence:

> there is a way to implement this method without resorting to an unsafe
>   cast or a raw type. The idea is to write a private helper method to
>   capture the wildcard type. The helper method must be a generic method
>   in order to capture the type. Here’s how it looks:
>
> ```
> public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
>     swapHelper(list, i, j);
> }
> // Private helper method for wildcard capture
> private static <E> void swapHelper(List<E> list, int i, int j) {
>     list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
> }
> ```

Finally, here is my implementation using type parameter:

```
 public static <E> void swap(List<E> list, int i, int j) {
        list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
  }
```

and the usage:

```
List<Object> integers = (...)
swap(integers, 1,2);
```

So, why sould I use wildcard instead?

The question is: why is the second way simpler? I can't see why! I miss some detail? I really want to understand what Bloch meant.

Comment: _There is no type parameter to worry about._

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand yet. :( There is some example? cause using type parameter I can use the method the same way. Using wildcard is worst, cause I need a helper method.

Comment: I don't understand. You have to be clear with your question and don't ask for opinions

Comment: The question is: why is the second way simpler? I can't see why! I miss some detail? I really want to understand what Bloch meant.

Comment: "There is no type parameter to worry about". It means I write less on method signature, without the <T> ? is it?

Comment: nobody can help me? =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, understand that Bloch is making a claim about *preference* here - you don't necessarily have to agree with him (and I have witnessed long and arduous discussions over this very point, so you're not the only one).

He does however spell out why he believes this is better. I'll try to pull out his key points so they're clearer.

> In a public API, the second is better because ... there is no type parameter to worry about. As a rule, if a type parameter appears only once in a method declaration, replace it with a wildcard....
>
> This slightly convoluted implementation ... allows us to export the nice wildcard-based declaration....
>
> Using wildcard types in your APIs, while tricky, makes the APIs far more flexible.

In other words Bloch is arguing that needing the `E` type is an implementation detail that you shouldn't expose to the client - a `swap()` method should work for any `List` therefore `?` is "correct" and exposing `E` in no way benefits the user. In a sense this is a generalization of *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*.

Note in particular that this advice is only directed at public APIs. There's no need to implement this workaround in code only you'll ever call.

This example is also arguably contrived - there really isn't a lot of difference between the two solutions, but hopefully you can imagine more complex methods that need a generic type as part of their implementation but not their public signature. Bloch's general point is that when a user doesn't need to know about a generic type you needn't impose that knowledge on them even if doing so seems trivial.